# How to generate exponential series of values with known initial and end values in Excel

Tags: excel, exponential

In Excel, I want to generate 1000 rows of values, I know the initial and final values.

For example, cell a1=1400 and cell a1000=1190, the total reduction is 15%, how to generate 1000 rows of values excel so that the values decrease exponentially?

Any idea how could I create a formula to achieve this? Thank you

Comment: What's the formula of the reduction? Could be as simple as putting A1 = 1400, and A2 = A1-row()*.3 or something like that

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon,t hanks for your reply, could you please explain more about this formula A2 = A1-row()*.3?

Comment: **What is the formula of the reduction?** There are any number of ways to achieve that change in value over that many cells; is this a math question or is it a programming question?

Comment: thank you for your reply,  I don't have the formula of reduction, basically I just want to create a series of number  so I can plot a graph exponentially with the fixed start and end values. it is a programming question, sorry I am really new to Excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]Suggested answer: Get the x variable on column A from 1 to 1000 and then create the y variable on column b so in x=1 y=1400,
And when x=1000 then y=1190
Then add chart with xy scatter and add power trend line. 
Set add equation on chart you will get y=1400X^-0.024. This will be your equation.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Sorry I am new to Excel. I have set the power trend line as mentioned. May I ask,  where can I set add equation on chart? and where can I see the equation?

Comment: on cell b3 add =1400*(A3)^-0.024

Answer (score 1):

Put 1 in A1, 2 in A2, 3 in A3 an so on... till A1000, then
write this in B1 `=1400.2278*EXP(-0.00016268*A1)` and continue to B1000, set B column 2 decimals format number.

**Exponential** regression equation is the form `y=a*e^(bx)`.

**Power** regression equation is the form `y=a*x^(b)`.

In excel EXP(x) function return `e^x`, e is euler number ~2.718281828 (Approximate)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried it out and it plotted a linear graph instead of exponential curve, did I make something wrong?

Comment: @user2563812 Almost a linear graph but no. Do you want a exponential or power formula? this is a math question (Grade 'Eh' Bacon is right)

Answer (score 1):

First type 1400 into A1 and 1190 in A1000.

Next, tap <kbd>F5</kbd> and when the GoTo dialog opens, type A1:A1000 in the Reference: text box and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Choose Home ► Editing ► Fill ► Series (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>,<kbd>FI</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>).

When the Series dialog opens, click <kbd>OK</kbd>. The increment (-0.21021021021021) will already be set.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, thank you especially for all the shortcut keys I have always wanted to know.  I tried it out and it plotted a linear graph instead of exponential curve, did I make something wrong?